# Why to use Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am building a news application and I receive news in JSON format.

One of my friends recommended me to use Retrofit, but I did not understand why I should use Retrofit library instead of just handling Json with Gson myself.

Is there some advantage of Retrofit that I am not aware of?

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is frown upon in software development.
Retrofit will make things easier for you!

Comment: You should code more your reinvented wheels, and then you'd answer to your question yourself.

Comment: See this advantages of Retrofit : http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/

Comment: Retrofit isn't only for parsing JSON. It will also make network calls so you dont have to write/maintain networking code by hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Retrofit will save your development time, And also you can keep your code in developer friendly. Retrofit has given almost all the API's to make server call and to receive response. internally they also use GSON to do the parsing. you can go through this link you will get more info
http://vickychijwani.me/retrofit-vs-volley/

Answer (score 6):

**Developing your own type-safe HTTP library to interface with a REST API can be a real pain: you have to handle many aspects, such as making connections, caching, retrying failed requests, threading, response parsing, error handling, and more. Retrofit, on the other hand, is a well-planned, documented and tested library that will save you a lot of precious time and headaches.**

Volley v/s Retrofit  see this link

http://vickychijwani.me/retrofit-vs-volley/

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'// compulsory

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0' //for retrofit conversion

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit 2 is great networking library for modern Android apps, but each has its own strengths that is worth weighing for critical projects. Use Retrofit if your use-case is a standard REST API with JSON responses and not too many custom requirements in terms of caching, request prioritization, retries, etc.